# Searching millions of strings between two textfile for exact matches (all-vs-all)

Tags: python, c++, c, bigdata, large-files

I have two text files. Both contain hundreds of millions of lines (rows). The second one is about four times larger.

Both text files have two columns each. The first one is an `ID` (key), the second one is the `Value` string which has to be compared between both files.

EDIT2: There might be duplicates in `Value` for both files.

Structure of both text files:

```
ID                      Value
B00CC0:2610:20880:13730 cd99AABABBABABABABABABABABA
B00CC0:2549:10230:33301 cd99BABABBABBBABBBBBBAAABBB
B00CC0:1272:8504:27179  cd99BBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAABBBBBB
B00CC0:1556:10628:35055 cd99AAAABBBBABABAAAAAAAAAAB
...                     ...
```

Now I want to output every line in the second file which contains a `Value` occurring in the first file (exact match, not a substring!).

I was trying a naive implementation in in Python via just loading both files to dataframes and then perform filtering:

```
import sys
import modin.pandas as pd

import ray
ray.init()

# load 1st file
data_one = pd.read_csv(filename1, compression='gzip', header=0, sep='\t', usecols=[1], names=['Value'])
data_one_list = data_tso['Value'].tolist()

# load 2nd file
data_two = pd.read_csv(filename2, compression='gzip', header=0, sep='\t', usecols=[0,1], names=['ID','alue'])

# filter
data_two_filtered = data_two[data_two['Value'].isin(data_one_list)]
```

However, this works only if I subset the first file otherwise it is too big and the Python script crashes (Eating up all the RAM). And it is too slow anyway. I was trying to use `modin.pandas` to speed up the entire process, but does not solve my problem.

Now I have questions going into two directions:

First direction:

1. Do you think it is possible to develop a solution with "decent" performance in Python? Or do you think C/C++ is needed (mentioning C/C++ since those are the only compiled languages I master at least enough to solve this problem)?

Second direction:

1. Do you think I have to use an approach such as a hash table or a trie for lookup or do you think a simple table lookup as tested is sufficient if done correctly?
2. If you suggest a specific approach, what would it be (data structure, approach)?

EDIT:

1. I have a machine with 256 GB RAM and 64 threads.
2. A decent speed would be to have this filtering performed within about 1-2 minutes max.

Comment: You forgot to tag FORTRAN, BASIC, Algol, Ada, Pascal and LISP.  If you are going to tag more than one language, you should tag a bunch more.  FORTRAN is good with large data sets.  BASIC is interpreted, so good at getting experiments up and running.

Comment: probably converting `data_one_list` to a set would speed things up, from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)` expected

Comment: On a Unix/Linux system, I'd just sort both files and then use the [`join`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) command.  (That is, I'd use C programs, that I don't have to write!)

Comment: See if your operating system supports memory-mapped files.  Let the OS manage the file and the memory.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I can not use "join" since the I am comparing the "Value" but if a "Value" is identical then the ID is not.

Comment: FYI, there is no language "C/C++".  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ allows overloaded functions and operators, C doesn't.  C++ has inheritance and access specifiers; C doesn't.

Comment: @Michael, I didn't suggest "join", but using memory mapped files.   Remember, when reading files, use the largest block size that you can.  Every transaction has an overhead.  You want to minimize the overhead per bytes (characters) read.

Comment: Most important is to get the algorithm right and then find a language to efficiently implement it in. There is this algorithm that at least works one way, searching a string in a very lon other string. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm might be worth a look. And check for libraries before implementing it yourself. C++ at least gives you quite a bit of control.

Comment: `sort -b -k 2 file1 > file1.sort; sort -b -k 2 file2 > file2.sort; join -1 2 -2 2 file1.sort file2.sort`

Comment: Or, if you're low on disk space and don't want to store both sorted files, you can use `sort -b -k 2 file2 | join -1 2 -2 2 file1.sort -`

Comment: What's the general value format? Is it always "cd99" followed by 23 "A" or "B"?

Comment: When using `join`, if you *only* want the common values (without the IDs), toss `-o 2.2` in with the other option flags.

Comment: As it is the value that is important for you, I would first sort on the scond key (linux: stg like sort -k2 ...)
Then I would loop reading a the first line of both file and who loop advancing on one file or the other depending with string is smaller, and print when they are equal.  This way you need minimal memory and you're just advancing in both files, without lopping and looping again (in O(n)), unless for the sort commands). Or use join as stated by others (don't know that command by heart)

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Especially: are you using the 64-bit version? Otherwise it could "crash" easily on very large files. The 64-bit version should have no problem with that (as long as you have enough memory available, but that doesn't seem to be the problem with your setup).

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, several solutions are possible. Since there is a lot of memory available on your computer, one could read the value column from the file line by line and add each value to a set.

After that one reads file 2 line by line and checks each value if it is in the set. If it is, then one outputs the current line buffer.

Such a C program is quickly written in < 100 lines of code, especially if you use an existing set implementation. I chose https://github.com/barrust/set because it looks good and is easy to integrate, just copy `set.c` and `set.h` into your project. For a quick test, I created a file with 100 million lines of random data with a similar structure as shown in your question.

It seems that with `set_init_alt` you can already set a high capacity for the hash table.

With
`gtime \-f\ "CPU: %Us\tReal: %es\tRAM: %MKB" ./search file1.txt file2.txt` I measured about **45 seconds** at **8.6GB RAM** for building the hash on my laptop, which seems to be a good result.

**C program**

The C program assumes that column 1 and column 2 are separated by spaces. It is easily adaptable if other separators are to be used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "set.h"

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 128

static char *get_value(char *buf);

static void error_exit(char *prefix, char *msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", prefix, msg);
    exit(-1);
}

static void build_set(char *fileName, SimpleSet *set) {
    char buf[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL) {
        error_exit("failure opening file1", strerror(errno));
    }

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) != NULL) {
        char *value = get_value(buf);
        set_add(set, value);
    }
    if (ferror(fp)) {
        error_exit("error reading from file1", strerror(errno));
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

static void query_set(char *fileName, SimpleSet *set) {
    char buf[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL) {
        error_exit("failure opening file2", strerror(errno));
    }

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) != NULL) {
        char *value = get_value(buf);
        if (set_contains(set, value) == SET_TRUE) {
            printf("%s\n", buf);
        }
    }
    if (ferror(fp)) {
        error_exit("error reading from file2", strerror(errno));
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

static char *get_value(char *buf) {
    char *ptr = buf;
    while (*ptr && *ptr != ' ')
        ptr++;
    while (*ptr == ' ')
        ptr++;
    char *value = ptr;
    while (*ptr && *ptr != '\n')
        ptr++;
    *ptr = '\0';
    return value;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 3) {
        error_exit("usage", "search <file1> <file2>");
    }

    SimpleSet set;
    set_init_alt(&set, 500000000, NULL);  /* use default hash */
    build_set(argv[1], &set);
    query_set(argv[2], &set);

    //the cleanup takes some time, but since the program terminates anyway, not necessary
    //set_destroy(&set);

    return 0;
}
```

**Build command**

```
 gcc -Wall -Wextra main.c set.c -O3 -o search
```

**Last remark**

This is certainly not a perfect, fully optimized version, and of course far more advanced solutions could be developed, but perhaps it is a starting point for your own experiments.